# How to find the exchange rate between two currency using PHP

Tags: php

```
I need to know exchange rate between two currency using PHP.
```

I have two currency namly USD,INR. I want to konw the exchnage rate between USD and INR.

How can I do. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use a free online web API like https://openexchangerates.org/.

API example here:

https://openexchangerates.org/documentation#example-php-curl